# Index page links goes to wrong pages when thesis has restarted page numbers

Tags: page-numbering, indexing, thesis, makeindex

I use [`ucbthesis`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ucbthesis?lang=en) for my thesis. We should have the abstract page to be numbered as page 1. The `ucbthesis` creates page numbers with order

```
1 (title page)
2 (approval page)
3 (copyright page)
1 (abstract page)
i, ii, iii, ..., viii (lists, etc)
1 (chapter one starts), 2, 3, ...
```

**The problem:**

In chapter 1, if I have an `\index{...}` placed anywhere in pages 1,2,3, the link of the index on the index page links to the pages 1,2,3 of the beginning of the document, not the pages 1,2,3 of the chapter 1. If the index is placed in pages 4,5 and over, they are linked correctly. Here is a simple code.

```
\documentclass{ucbthesis}

\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\title{\normalfont{Title ...}}
\author{Author ...}
\degreesemester{Semester ...}
\degreeyear{Year ...}
\degree{Degree ...}
\chair{Professor ...}
\othermembers{Professor ...}
\numberofmembers{4}
\field{Mathematics}
\campus{Berkeley}

\maketitle
\approvalpage
\copyrightpage

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{dedication}
\null\vfil
\begin{center}
Dedication here ...
\end{center}
\vfil\null
\end{dedication}

\end{frontmatter}
\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}
Lebesgue space\index{Lebesgue space} ...

\printindex

\end{document}
```

How can I set page links to point to the second series of page numbers?

Comment: This is certainly a solution, though I do not prefer to compiler the document twice, one with desired page numbers after front matter, and one with desired pages before front matter, then break the two pdf and merge desired sections. I feel there should be a way to instruct makeindex to look for the right pages, or perhaps an alternative index package that I am not aware of.